# Pycharm 2022.1 (Professional edition) not showing Pandas Series plots in scientific mode even after "Show Plots in Tools Window" option is checked

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, series, exploratory-data-analysis

> I don't see any plots or data in "Scientific Mode" in Pycharm
> professional edition 2022.1. The option to show plots in settings is
> checked. I restarted Pycharm several times and of no use. Please help.
> I am trying to plot a pandas Series bar plot.

[image]